# What are the standard Annotations provided by the Apple iOS MapKit?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

In looking through all of the Apple MapKit documentation, the only "standard" annotation Views I could find were the following:

- [MKAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html): Base view, useful for displaying static images as annotations.
- [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html): Displays a Pin as the annotation for a point on the map.

Are there any other standard Annotation Views that Apple provides?  Do they provide one with just a dot?  Or a Dot with text?

Comment: You are totally correct there are only to annotation views, but you can easily create your own.

Comment: Technically, MKAnnotationView is the base class and MKPinAnnotationView is the only "standard" ready-made subclass of MKAnnotationView that draws anything ready-made for you (a "pin").

Comment: @Anna The MKAnnotationView, while a base class, can also be used to present a static image.  So I put it in the same category as an "out-of-the-box" annotation view.

Comment: @JohnFowler, Yes, as long as you set its `image` property or add some subview otherwise, it will be invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the only two *provided by Apple*.  You can, of course, create your own. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW2):

> ### Defining a Custom Annotation View
>
> If a static image is insufficient for representing your annotation, you can subclass MKAnnotationView and draw content dynamically in one of the following two ways:
>
> - Continue to use the image property of MKAnnotationView, but change the image at regular intervals.
> - Override the annotation view’s drawRect: method and draw your content dynamically every time.
>
> ...